# Mouse with consistent long-lasting surface traction/friction

Tags: mice

I am a heavy desktop and mouse user, and I like using mice right on the desk surface i.e. without a mouse pad. This involves keeping the desk squeaky clean but I am okay with it.

The issue is that all mice that I have tried start developing a noticeable surface friction after about 4 months of use. Typically what happens is the rubber pads attached to the mouse start wearing out, and that causes an increased friction. Moving the mouse around starts getting a bit tiresome.

What I do then is remove the rubber pads from the mouse completely so that the contact surface becomes bare plastic. Then the friction almost goes away until the plastic starts wearing out. Finally I just buy a new mouse which lasts another 4-6 months.

Are there any modern mice models that somehow overcome the above woes?

Comment: What's your desk surface made of? I stopped using mouse mats back in the 90s & the average life-span of a mouse since then has been about a decade. Usually the buttons fail around the same time as i'd need new feet [which are mere pence on eBay, btw]

Comment: @Tetsujin Just typical painted chipboard office desk. Maybe my hand is oversensitive and asking too much, dunno.

Comment: Either you're pressing far harder than I can imagine, or your desktop is made of sandpaper;) I just can't imagine wearing the feet out in a few months.

Comment: @Tetsujin It doesn't wear out, only _starts_ to: the surface becomes not as easily skidding as when new.

Answer (score 0):

There is a substance known as HDPE, high density polyethylene. It's a very slippery but very durable plastic, commonly seen in cutting boards. Another similar produce is UHMWPE, ultrahigh molecular weight polyethylene. Unfortunately, it's also challenging to create a bond using adhesives. A thin slice or slices/pads of this plastic would last much longer than the usual pads, but the problem lies in the adhesive.

I have resources including a hobby grade milling machine and lathe and would consider to create a barb in the plastic stock, then shaving/turning away all but the barb and a thin pad for surface contact. This sort of thing could be done with extremely sharp hand tools, or another method of attachment devised.

[image: push rivet sample]

This image is a rough representation of my suggestion, although far too large for your purpose. [Image from Amazon product link.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DETDKLO) One could get away with a smaller, thinner pad and only the cone tip of this image.